# Memory leak found, but I can't find it?

Tags: iphone

After using Run->Run with Performance tool->Leaks on my application, it finds a leak, but I don't know if it is a glitch by the tool?

1. I start the application by selecting a button, which opens a tableview (no leaks).
2. tableview appears and if I don't touch anything (no leaks).
3. If I select the first cell and cursor appears blinking (3 to 4 seconds later, leak)??

I did find something weird, in my tableview, if I try selecting any other cell, besides the first one, it will not become the first responder (this might not have to do with anything)?

If anyone has come across this or can spot or direct me to where this could be happening please let me know?  Thank you.

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) { 
   cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];  
}    
      // Configure the cell... 
   UITextField *FirstField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 130, 25)];
   FirstField.delegate = self;
   FirstField.tag = indexPath.row; [cell.contentView addSubview:FirstField]; 
   FirstField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyNext; 
   [FirstField release];
   return cell; 
}
```

Comment: please edit your question and post your code inline.  It's hard to read it in a comment to an answer ...

Comment: i don't think it's the answer for your problem, but i think when you dequeue a cell, you add yet another textfield, where there was already one. if you scroll a lot, you could run out of memory just by adding too many textfields to the cell.contentView.

maybe the problem isnt in this function, are you `alloc`ing anything else in the controller?

Comment: Is there a way you can use the performance tool to pin point where it is taking place?

Answer (score 1):

The memory leak is that due to every time you call the function you are allocating a UITextField and adding it to the cell.

Cells are reused and each time the cell is accessed to determine the content a new UITextField is added to the cell and stacked onto of each other

Move the allocation of FirstField to where the cell is allocated so that it can be reused.

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) { 
   cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];  
   UITextField *FirstField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 130, 25)];
   FirstField.tag = 1
   [cell.contentView addSubview:FirstField];
   [FirstField release];
}    
UITextField *field = (UITextField *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:1];
field.delegate = self;
field.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyNext; 
return cell;
```

I also see that you are using the field.tag to store the indexPath.row value of the cell, in that cause you might have to search the view hirachy of cell.contentView to find the TextField subview.

Comment: Hi richerd, I tried your fix, but [cell.contentView.viewWithTag:1]; gives an error (request for member 'content' in something not a structure or union)??

Comment: sorry typo, should be UITextField *field = (UITextField *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:1];